# Generating a number in a class in Python gets me a weird error

Tags: python, function, class

So I am new to class in Python but not new to classes in general.
I want to generate a new number in the object I create, and constantly change it.

So I did

```
    class ArmedBandit1:
        num = 0
        def spin():
            num = random(10)
    
    a1 = ArmedBandit1()
    
    a1.spin()
    print(a1.num)
```

Now I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    a1.spin()
TypeError: spin() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But I didn't give it any arguments, and if I try to remove the "()" it ignores the method.

Comment: Try `def spin(self):`

Comment: Why are you using a class attribute for this? It should be `self.num`, so you can have multiple instances with different spins.

Answer (score 2):

Define with **self** as first parameter! Define **init** and assign property! (To get random number in a range use `random.randrange(10)`)

```
import random
class ArmedBandit1:
  def __init__(self):
    self.num = 0
  def spin(self):
    self.num = random.randrange(10)
  
    
a1 = ArmedBandit1()
a1.spin()
print(a1.num)
```

[basics of python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike67 suggested in the comments, you need to include the parameter `self` to have the method work for a particular instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the object to assign a variable to it, you must create a **init**() function. You must also use the self keyword to refer to the object that you're creating. Here's an example with your code:

```
import random

class ArmedBandit1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def spin(self):
        self.num = random.randrange(10)

a1 = ArmedBandit1()

a1.spin()
print(a1.num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Code!

```
import random
class ArmedBandit1:
    def spin(self):
        return random.randrange(10)

a1 = ArmedBandit1()

print(a1.spin())
```

Thank you to the help above!!